# How do I use getline to read from a file and then tokenize it using strtok?

Tags: c++

I want my program to read lines from a file using `getline()`, and then tokenize the words using `strtok()`, and put them into a two-dimensional array.

I understand there are probably way better ways to do this, but I am limited by what I've learned so far and the assignment requirements.

I've tried using these threads/sites to refer to for help:

[C++ strtok() tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstring/strtok)

[using getline to read from file in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67133535/)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char words[100][16]; //Holds the words
    int uniquewords[100]; //Holds the amount of times each word appears
    int counter; //counter

    if (argc = 2)
    {
        cout << "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter the names of the files again. \n";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputfile;

    inputfile.open(argv[1]);
    outputfile.open(argv[2]);

    char *token;
    while(inputfile.getline(words, 100))
    {
        token = strtok(words[100][16], " ");
        cout << token;
    }
}
```

The error message I'm getting is

> error: no matching function to call to 'std::basic_ifstream::getline(char [100][16], int)'

Comment: There are way better alternatives than `strtok()` to split, read words from the line.

Comment: Don't pass `words` to getline - it is a 2d array - pass `words[i]` so that one string is read into one index of the array (you will need a for loop so that you have an index)

Comment: Also `token = strtok(words[100][16], " ");` is completely wrong.  You are passing a single character that is past the end of your array.  You want to pass `words[i]` so that you pass one string (you will need a for loop so that you have an index)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Although I'm guessing the OP's note about "I am limited by what I've learned so far and the assignment requirements" probably means they're stuck with C-string APIs (no use of `std::getline`, `std::string`, `std::istringstream`, etc.; instead, while they use a *little* of the C++ `iostream` API, they only use it to work with C-style strings as `char[]` which then tokenize with `strtok`). *sigh* I'm cool with teaching low level C stuff, but it's very weird to claim you're teaching them C++ while teaching them incredibly unidiomatic C++.

Comment: A note: If you could really use C++, not "C with a tiny bit of C++ for I/O", you'd want to base this on [one of the answers to "How do I iterate over the words of a string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/364696) which shows a idiomatic ways to split a string either on individual space characters (what you're trying to do), or on runs of whitespace (the more commonly desired outcome). You'd read each line with `std::getline` (not the `getline` method of the file) to get a `std::string` per line, then use `std::istringstream` in some way to extract tokens one by one as `std::string`s.

Comment: The function to use in C++ is `get()`. Give a sec and I’ll write up an answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, sorry I don't really follow with what you're saying, but the assignment specifically details I can't use C++ string objects at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the line

```
if (argc = 2)
```

is probably not doing what you intend. You should probably write this instead:

```
if (argc == 2)
```

The function [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) requires as a first parameter a `char *`, which is the address of a memory buffer to write to. However, you are passing it the 2D array `words`, which does not make sense.

You could theoretically pass it `words[0]`, which has space for `16` characters. Passing `words[0]` will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) to `&words[0][0]`, which is of the required type `char *`. However, the size of `16` characters will probably not be sufficient. Also, it does not make sense to write the whole line into `words`, as this 2D array seems to be intended to store the result of `strtok`.

Therefore, I recommend that you introduce an additional array that is supposed to store the entire line:

```
char line[200];
(...)
while( inputfile.getline( line, sizeof line ) )
```

Also, the line

```
token = strtok(words[100][16], " ");
```

does not make sense, as you are accessing the array `words` out of bounds. Also, it does not make sense to pass a 2D array to `std::strtok`, either.

Another issue is that you should call `std::strtok` several times, once for every token. The first parameter of `std::strtok` should only be non-`NULL` on the first invocation. It should be `NULL` on all subsequent calls, unless you want to start tokenizing a different string.

After copying all tokens to `words`, you can then print them in a loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char line[200];
    char words[100][16];
    int counter = 0;

    ifstream inputfile;

    inputfile.open(argv[1]);

    while( inputfile.getline( line, sizeof line) )
    {
        char *token;

        token = strtok( line, " ");

        while ( token != nullptr )
        {
            strcpy( words[counter++], token );
            token = strtok( nullptr, " " );
        }
    }

    //print all found tokens
    for ( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ )
    {
        cout << words[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

For the input

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
```

the program has the following output:

```
This
is
the
first
line.
This
is
the
second
line.
```

As you can see, the strings were correctly tokenized.

However, note that you will be writing to the array `words` out of bounds if

- any of the tokens has a size larger than 16 characters, or
- the total number of tokens is higher than 100.

To prevent this from happening, you could add additional checks and abort the program if such a condition is detected. An alternative would be to use a `std::vector` of `std::string` instead of a fixed-size array of C-style strings. That solution would be more flexible and would not have the problems mentioned above.

Comment: Assuming I don't go over 100 characters per line, would it be ok if I made line[100]?

Comment: @KevinNguyen: Yes, it would be ok. I just selected `200` as an arbitrary number which seemed reasonable, but if you are sure that you don't need more than `100`, then you can reduce it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To read a string into a character array using C++, use `std::cin.get()`. You can then tokenize the string using `strtok()` if you wish.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char   s[1000];
  char * words[100] = {nullptr};  // each char* points to a piece of s[]
  int    size = 0;
  
  std::cout << "s? ";
  std::cin.get( s, sizeof(s) );
  
  const char * delimiters = " ";  // " .!:;,?" etc
  
  for (char * token = strtok( s, delimiters );  token;  token = strtok( NULL, delimiters ))
  {
    words[size++] = token;  // this just adds each word to the list
  }
  
  for (int n = 0;  n < size;  n++)
    std::cout << (n+1) << ": " << words[n] << "\n";
}
```

If you wish to count how many words are unique, you need to use a slightly different method than just adding the word to the end of an array. Instead, look through the array to see if the word is already there. If it is, increment its corresponding count:

```
char * words [100] = {nullptr};
int    counts[100] = {0};
int    size = 0;

n = index of word in words[], or size if word is not in words[]
counts[n] += 1;
words[n] = word;
```

You will need `strcmp()` to determine if the `word` is equal to a word found in `words[]`:

```
if (strcmp( word, words[n] ) == 0)
```

#### Choice of array: `char * words[100]` vs `char words[100][16]`

Notice how I am not using `strcpy()`. This is because I am simply using the *address* of each word found in `s`. If you modify `s`, you break your words. Nevertheless, if you do not plan to modify `s` then it is how I recommend you do it.

However, you can, if you wish, `strcpy()` the words found in `s` to a `words[][]` array as you have it in your current code:

```
char words[100][16];
int size = 0;

for (char * token = ...)
{
  strcpy( words[size++], token );
}
```

This presumes, however, that every word you find will definitely be 15 characters or fewer. You can use `strncpy()` to make sure that each word does not overflow your `words[n][]` buffer.

IMHO all this string copying just makes life a little more difficult for you. Though it does mean you can reuse `s` without ruining any of the words you have already stored in `words[]`.